# HP Stream 13-C004TU Notebook for Ubuntu Install

Tags: system-installation, laptop, hp

I'm looking at purchasing this [HP Stream 13-C004TU Notebook](http://www.harveynorman.com.au/computers-tablets/computers/laptops/hp-stream-13-c004tu-notebook-blue.html), as I am wanting to install Ubuntu 14.10 and not wanting to spend more than $300.

The questions I have are:

1. Will this spec be sufficient to run the latest version of Ubuntu either through a VM or complete rebuild to run Ubuntu?
2. Do people see any issues in performance with running Ubuntu overall install using this HP Notebook?

Comment: The **HP Stream 11** will however run Ubuntu **14.10** (64-bit). I have added details in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

for **HP Stream 13**: (or HP Stream 11)

Adapted in part from: [Amazon.com > Kyle's review > 'HP Stream 11'](http://www.amazon.com/review/R28HR668I6LU8Y)

**Notes:**

- No changes required to BIOS settings, uses (default) UEFI settings (as supplied);
- Notebook does NOT support 32-bit Ubuntu, due to UEFI issues;

**Create *Ubuntu Install* USB drive:** (on a different PC)

- Download **14.04** .iso file;
- Insert 2GB (or larger) USB drive; (*any content will be erased*)
- Start *Disk Utility*; (aka 'Disks')

  - Select the USB drive;
  - Click on 'cog' icon, at top right
  - Select '*Restore Disk Image*', and navigate to .iso file;
  - Click 'Start Restoring'

**Install *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS* on HP Stream 13 (or 11) Notebook:**

- Insert USB drive in USB 2.0 slot; (the USB 3.0 slot can cause issues)
- Power on Notebook;
- When screen backlight goes on (after 1.5 seconds), press <kbd>F9</kbd> key; (above 8/9 keys)
- Choose USB drive, as UEFI source;
- Choose 'Install Ubuntu';
- When prompted for language (and not before), enable WiFi connection;
- Select 'download updates' (during install);
- Proceed with normal install; (I chose to replace/erase **Windows 8.1**);
- Once install completes, load all updates.

*Only remaining issue is time to boot (to logon screen), from cold start: (20-24 seconds, in total)*

---

**UPDATE:** 2015-Apr-11

This bug (kernel issues with **eMMC**) has been identified and 'fixed', with this due to appear in future updates to **14.04 LTS** or later.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1333140

*This should remove the **cold start** pause/delay (additional 14-17 seconds).*

Comment: Thanks for your help on this - I think I might actually go with this notebook. Can I ask which faster/lighter 7200 RPM variant HDD you went with (exact model no./brand pls would be great)?

Comment: I'm looking at getting the same setup as you together with swapping out the drive. Can you let me know how to go about installing the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit onto the faster 7200RPM drive prior to actually swapping it out with the 5400RPM?

Comment: I am going to order a HDD enclosure and setup Ubuntu on the new drive and then swap it out with the existing drive. Unsure where the UEFI fits in but am I on the right track for now?

Comment: I also want to upgrade the RAM up to 8GB (Max.) but am not sure if this only requires one stick alone and if this 8GB RAM is compatible with it: http://www.scorptec.com.au/product/Memory/SODIMM/52039-KVR16LS11_8

Comment: WiFi isn't working for me with Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Can you please raise that issue, as its **own** question.

Comment: on my HP stream 14  I needed to press F10 to go to Bios

Answer (score 3):

I am writing this on an HP Stream 13 (Same as 11, just larger screen). The only issue (kinda a big one) that I have run into with this running Ubuntu 14.10 is with the eMMC they have for a boot drive. I don't know all the terminology, but here it is in plain language. There is a tiny partition on the eMMC that is confusing Ubuntu. I think it's called or labeled RPMP, and Ubuntu can't access it. It is at the beginning sectors of the drive, so Ubuntu tries to read it, but can't. This significantly slows the boot time (Approx. 4 minutes for me) and has also interfered when installing new kernel updates through the Ubuntu Software Center. I read somewhere that there is a fix, but I haven't seen it yet. I am hopeful that it makes it's way into Ubuntu 15.04, or this could be a very annoying computer to have.

Comment: Did this issue get fixed in later versions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this from an HP Stream Mini desktop running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit), so I'm proof it can be done. (From what I've read the Stream Mini desktop is basically the same system as the notebook, just in a different form factor.)

The process isn't hard, but it's hard to find out exactly HOW to do it.

I'll assume you already know how or can find out how to put Ubuntu onto a bootable USB stick. The trick is getting the HP to boot to that stick.

**Long story short: you need to press F10 at boot to get to the UEFI/BIOS configuration.** Just change the boot order so your USB stick comes before the hard drive.

**If you are unable to find your USB Drive, try switching boot options to "Legacy", saving those settings and retrying F9**

A lot of stuff out there mentions pressing F12, but that just brings up UEFI boot options, which won't show the USB stick.

I am planning to do a full write up of this on my blog soon (I'll post a link here when I do), but for anyone with some experience installing Ubuntu, I'm guessing the only problem you'll have is getting the USB stick to boot.

It's also possible to tell the system to boot to the USB stick by navigating a labyrinth of options within Windows 8.1, but that only works until you've overwritten Windows. I've installed Ubuntu 3 times on this machine now. (Don't ask... it's not because it didn't work, it's because my experimentation got out of hand and I needed a clean start.)

I will say that once you get Ubuntu installed, it is smooth as butter. This is not a powerful machine but it handles Ubuntu really well. I have not run into any hardware compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response @room34. I am actually new to this so am not entirely sure how to put Ubuntu onto a bootable USB stick. Are you able to provide some pointers or do I have to wait for your blog post? Actually can you pls share your blog url. Any help will be great. FYI, I have decided to go with the HP 250 G3 setup - will this make a difference?

Comment: I just finished the first draft of the blog post: [http://blog.room34.com/archives/5260](http://blog.room34.com/archives/5260) I hope this is helpful. Since I don't have the HP Stream Mini with me at the moment I couldn't get into the details of the UEFI/BIOS configuration. But I did outline the process for preparing the USB stick _on a Mac_ which is my experience. If you're on a Linux system already it's basically the same I think, but you don't need to mess with the .iso to .img conversion.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you need to use third-party utilities, but the [official Ubuntu docs](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) have instructions. Good luck!

Comment: The hard part is creating a viable USB-installer. *The most effective method is ask-a-friend, and have them create it on an existing **Ubuntu 14.04** PC.* **You don't need to muck with boot order. Just use <F9>, to choose the device to boot from.**