# Ubuntu 14 on HP Stream with 32GB eMMC. Please help before I buy!

Tags: hp, stream, emmc

I want to buy a laptop, wipe it and install Ubuntu 14.x.x on it. 
I saw this HP Stream with this specs:

Celeron N3060
speed1.6 GHGz
Graphics  cardIntel GMA HD
Ram 2 GB 
SSD  32 GB (eMMC)

Do you think I can Install Ubuntu 14 on this one?
Im suspicious of the eMMC disk in particular.

Thank you all.

Comment: You might also consider sticking [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) on it instead of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Melebius - No, that's not a dupe.

Comment: Seems the answer is no http://askubuntu.com/questions/785121/installing-ubuntu-16-04-lte-on-emmc-storage but IDK that for a fact.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu will run perfectly fine on the Stream. 32 GB eMMC will be slightly tight, but will be faster than a standard 5400rpm hard disk. 2GB of RAM is also slightly tight, but shouldn't be a problem for normal use.

Edit: There were issues in the kernel concerning eMMC on the Stream. However, several people have successfully installed and the kernel issues have been fixed. See this link:

> [HP Stream 13-C004TU Notebook for Ubuntu Install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578187/hp-stream-13-c004tu-notebook-for-ubuntu-install)

Edit2: There seems to be a few network issues concerning the Broadcom wireless card.

Comment: There are quite a few questions with people saying Ubuntu won't install to the EMMC: http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/emmc

Comment: There are quite a few people that have successfully installed Ubuntu to the eMMC on the HP Stream. Kernel issues with the eMMC have been fixed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/578187/hp-stream-13-c004tu-notebook-for-ubuntu-install. Please do research on the specific model before downvoting and/or posting.

Comment: If you edit your answer to include that link, I'll reverse the downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

I have x2 HP Stream 14 laptops running Antergos and they run beautifully. I imagine that ubuntu will run equally well.

In order to boot from usb I had to enter bios (f10 on startup), enable legacy mode in boot options, set usb as 1st boot.

I'm not sure on the install of ubuntu but I had to manually make partitions for the home,swap,ESP which I did with help from here:

https://antergos.com/wiki/install/how-to-dual-boot-antergos-windows-uefi-expanded-by-linuxhat/

I imagine Ubuntu might be a simpler install and should work fine, but I can vouch the Antergos runs like a dream!